# Right ideals in a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

> Are there right ideals of $M_n(k)$ other than those of the form of zeroing one or more rows at a time?

For example you can take first row to be zero and this is a right ideal. My question is are there ideals other than those of this form?

Comment: You just have to pick something likely and *check*. It isn't hard at all to find an example that way.

Comment: A generalization of this example would be: let $W$ be a linear subspace of $k^n$.  Then the matrices of $M_n(k)$ such that every column is in $W$ is a right ideal of $M_n(k)$.  (So in rschwieb's example, $W$ is the span of $(1, 1)$.  And in your example, $W$ is the subspace of vectors with some entries fixed to 0.)

Comment: In fact, I've convinced myself *every* right ideal of $M_n(k)$ is of this form for some subspace $W$ - and the proof is such that it could reasonably be a problem in an upper-division undergraduate course.  If you're interested, you could try to work out a proof, and then post another question if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for example

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}M_2(k)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\a&b \end{bmatrix}\middle|\,a,b\in k\right\}$$

It has nonzero entries in all rows, but it is clearly not the entire ring.

Another counting argument that works for infinite $k$: There are only $2^n$ possibilities for the ideals you're describing, but there are infinitely many right ideals if $k$ is infinite. (Even if $k$ is finite the example above shows that finiteness does not help.)

Answer (score 2):

As a generalization of your example, let $W$ be a linear subspace of $k^n$.  Then the set of $n \times n$ matrices such that every column is in $W$, or equivalently, $\{ A \in M_n(k) \, | \, CS(A) \subseteq W \}$, is a right ideal of $M_n(k)$.  (The additivity, and containing 0, are fairly easy; for the right multiplication condition, use the fact that $CS(AB) \subseteq CS(A)$.)

In your example, $W$ is the subspace of vectors with the corresponding elements of the vector equal to 0.  And in rschwieb's example, $W$ is the span of $(1, 1)$.

In fact, it turns out that *every* right ideal of $M_n(k)$ is of this form for some subspace $W$.  The proof isn't conceptually hard (though it might possibly be cumbersome notation-wise).